# Reason Meta Link on Edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, review, suggested-edits

We have comments for questions, and custom close reason.  We don't have a good system for **communicating** with editors and reviewers **to effect consensus**.

The key to StackExchange is the people working together, especially those that edit, close, flag, comment, etc.  I propose new field that should appear when editing, review edits, and rollingback edits.  It would have a similar interface to Duplicate Close dialog, where you can search or put in a URL.

The link would be shown to the editor and any reviewers that reviewed in a contrary way.

A lot of the problem, is **people simply don't see every post on meta**.  This will help unite the users that edit posts by providing a basis for a decision.  It will also help new users to see why their edit was rejected, with more detail than one of the five reasons.

I know the edit function offers a "edit summary" field, but this is hardly the best place for such a link, and they often go unnoticed.  Also, the edit summary can only be utilized when you edit or improve an edit, and it doesn't notify reviewers.

This will especially help with the ongoing too minor questions, or `those` `that` put `every` other `word` in code tags`,` but can help alleviate any future trends of poor editing, approval, or rejection.

In the edit dialog, it would show up when you select a reason.

[image: edit dialog suggestion]

It would also be available on the improve and edit views.
[image: edit reason]

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: It's a feature request, I'm requesting a feature :-)  Is there a specific part you would like me to clarify?

Comment: What is the request? I'm having a hard time understanding it.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, do the pictures add any clarity?

Comment: I'm with @ColeJohnson.  I don't really follow this.  What are these links you are adding pointing to on Meta?

Comment: To point to a consensus on a certain issue.  Otherwise we get a lot of 2:3 approve:reject responses to questions, even though it's been decided that similar questions **should** be rejected or accepted.  Basically an edit comes down to luck of the draw, especially when people have recently acquired 2k, but don't really know what the community wants.  There 1300+ questions on meta about [suggested-edits] and people just don't know about them.  It'd be a chance to improve reviewers ability to review consistently.  I'll add some links to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To point to a consensus on a certain issue. Otherwise we get a lot of 2:3 approve:reject responses to questions, even though it's been decided that similar questions should be rejected or accepted. Basically an edit comes down to luck of the draw, especially when people have recently acquired 2k, but don't really know what the community wants. There 1300+ questions on meta about [suggested-edits] and people just don't know about them. It'd be a chance to improve reviewers ability to review consistently.

Eh, I understand where you are going with this but, IMO, it won't work.  I've long been a fan of trying to educate the mid-rep users (1K to 5K) on site policies and preferences and previous consensuses on specific issues, but there are 2 major issues with this approach

1. By the time you find the correct link on Meta and paste it into the box, someone else will have already reviewed the edit and moved on.
2. Not enough reviewers and/or editors will care enough to provide the links to make this feature work as designed.

I also think the premise you are suggesting that many of the split vote reviews are due to lack of education is not accurate.  I do think education is part of it, but I you also have issues where there is no community consensus on specific issues or the community is split on a specific issue.  But the biggest factors are poor edit summaries that cause some reviewers to misunderstand the reasons for edits, reviewers reviewing too quickly, and not using the skip button enough.

So to summarize, the core idea of educating editors and reviewers is a good one, but I think this approach isn't the right way to do it.

Comment: Fair enough.  Have any other suggestions?  There's basically no forum for this currently, other than leaving a comment on the question/answer being edited. Is that the way to go?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand If you are trying to communicate with an editor, pinging them with an @-comment works well on the post they edited.  For communicating with the reviewers, there's not really anything at this point.